# Angular 2 + Laravel API EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 0 for URL: null

Tags: angular, laravel-5, http-post, backend

In my angular 2 app, I wrote a simple post request which always returns this error:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 0  for URL: null
```

After some search I found that it might be a CORS issue, so I've implemented a CORS class on my API backend:

use Closure;

```
class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $http_origin = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] : false; 
        $allowed_origins = ['http://sub.example.com' , 'http://localhost', 'http://localhost:4200', 'http://localhost:3000'];


            if(in_array($http_origin, $allowed_origins)) {
                return $next($request)->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*')
                  ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE')
                  ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
            }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Also what I tried is to add additional route for OPTIONS:

```
Route::options('{all}', function () {

    $response = Response::make('');

    if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) && in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], ['http://localhost:4200'])) {
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    } else {
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', url()->current());
    }
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
    $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    $response->header('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff');

    return $response;
});


Route::options('{all}', 'HomeController@options')->where('all', '.*');


//JWT AUTHENTIFICATION
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function () {

    //if throws CORS error - put all routes in this cors middleware group

    /*  MAILER ROUTES */
    Route::post('/sendSingleEmail', 'HomeController@sendSingleEmail');
```

On my other project, this configuration works pretty fine, but for new project always receive this error.

Angular 2 Code:

sendSingleMail() {

```
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  var creds = "data";

  this.http
  .post("http://api.mailer.dev/sendSingleEmail", JSON.stringify(creds))
  .toPromise()
  .then(res => console.log(res))//res.json().data)
  .catch(this.handleError);



}

private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {

    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}
```

I've also tried to use different headers but no result. Does anybody else have this issue ? Any suggestions how to solve ?

Comment: I've tried to use Chrome with Allow Cross Origin Extension and it worked. Seems like its a Laravel 5 CORS issue. But Im using this backend which works perfectly with other angular app, but doesnt allow current app requests. What could be the issue

Comment: Solved, admin can delete the topic

Comment: Could you tell what provided the solution? I've a similar issue on GET requests towards a Web Api 2 written in c#, except the api allows CORS from all origin.

Comment: Actually the issue was my browser Firefox, plugin was blocking scripts.

Comment: Hmmm that's not my issue, i've the same issue with firefox and chrome. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Then most probably the issue is CORS issue from backend on your side. You need to allow CORS on your backend API

Comment: Yes, I did that already, and I have the CORS headers when I try with postman. 

That's why I find this strange :/